# Grabbing the OS release with grep and sed

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression

I'm currently trying to grab my OS release using the following shell command:

```bsh
echo $(lsb_release -a) | grep -o 'Release:.*' | sed -n 's/.*Release: //p'
```

After trying many combinations listed in StackExchange this is the one that got me close to what I wanted. That being said this output isn't just the release number, it prints out the OS codename also; how can I grab only the release number? What am I missing?

Comment: `lsb_release -rs` doesn't work for you?

Comment: It does, thanksss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
lsb_release -s -r
```

or

```
lsb_release --short --release
```

This gives you the release number without the `Release:` heading.